# . or -> as Member Access operator in C++

Tags: c++11, visual-c++

I am quite new  to C++. My earlier programming experience is in Java.
As per my earlier knowledge to access members of class we only use '->' but of course that is not true as we can also use '.'(dot notation). Can somebody tell me when is suitable when?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's try to understand it using a simple example:

Suppose you have the following structure

```
struct myStructure
{
    int a;
    int b;
};
```

Now, you can access the fields `a` and `b` using two methods:

First using a `myStructure` variable:

```
myStructure x;
int aField = x.a;
int bField = x.b;
```

Second, using a pointer to `myStructure` :

```
myStructure * x;
int aField = x->a;
int bField = x->b;
```

So, the point is, if you have access to an object or instance of a class or structure, you access the individual members using `. operator` and when you have a pointer, you access the members using `-> operator`.

Comment: Ok,thanks. It makes quite sense to me now.But is there any preference which one is to be used over the other or not?

Comment: there is no such thing as a preferred way to do this. It totally depends on the situation. This is a simple example, in complex cases, pointers and declarations get more complicated to understand, but they do provide flexibility.

Answer (score 4):

`.` is for object, `->` is for pointer